# Rails safe params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xss

When passing params to the view, for example for a `link_to` I would like to create a hash based on expected params.

At the moment I have a private method on the controller

```
private

def safe_params
  @params = {
    foo: "bar"
  }
end
```

And I call this in the controller method

```
def some_method
  safe_params
end
```

And in the view

```
link_to "Something", @params[:foo]
```

Is there a better or simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: Depends. What are you exactly trying to do? Will the value of `foo` key change in different method/controller? or is it constant across all? Why do you even want to have such a dependency in your application code in the first place?

Comment: These params will mainly be used for query strings, like certain sections or page numbers. And they would be different for most methods on the controller which is why I asked the question. I don't really want to create a new method for each methods params.

Comment: This pattern will create pain sooner rather than later in development, as you'd have to be worried about what to set where in which method of this or that controller. I recommend you to move such scenarios: section and subsections, page numbers etc. to routes instead of keeping a track of them in params. However, your question is still unclear to me, as it doesn't state whether the value of keys in such hash would change or even the keys would change.

Comment: you can use a your own helper's method